# Append multiple variables with jquery

Tags: jquery, append

I have a var that I want to append multiple times with jQuery. The code is like so:

```
var number = 4;                      //number of times the html must be appended
html = $("<div>Content here</div>"); //The html I want to append
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").append(html * number); //Append the div multiple times
});
```

I'm wondering how I can make the html var append the amount of times mentioned in the number var (4)? The code above doesn't work, and I can see why. But I can't see a way to fix it. Any ideas? (I'm not a great expert at jQuery!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this remove `$` also

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var number = 4; 
    html = "<div>Content here</div>";
    for(var i=0;i< number;i++)       
    {
         $("body").append(html);
    }
   });
```

[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JjGPt/)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `*`operator between a jQuery object (`html`) and a number (`number`).
You will have to use a loop for it, like:

```
$(function() {
var number = 4;
  var i = 0;
  var container = $("body");
  for (i = 0; i < number; i += 1) {
    var html = $("<div>Content here</div>");
    container.append(html);
  }
});
```

**EDIT:** Put `html` in the loop.

Comment: have to remove $ otherwise it will not get append multiple times

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this Code:-


    $(function() {` 
      for (var i = 0; i<4; i++) {
        $("body").append( ("<div>Content here</div>"));
      }
    });
```

Comment: it will not work with $ in this  $("<div>Content here</div>")

Answer (score 0):

Calling `append` multiple times is slow, especially in a loop. Compile the DOM objects from your string only once, for efficient results use `array.join()` and an array as a string builder. Also you would prefer to use appendTo rather than append as it is faster.

Example:

```
var number = 4;                      //number of times the html must be appended
var content = "<div>Content here</div>";           //The html I want to append
var stringBuilder = [];
for (var i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    stringBuilder.push(content);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(stringBuilder.join('')).appendTo($("body")); //Append the compiled string to the body
});
```